# How do I create a dynamic SVG background for any screen size?

Tags: react-native, svg

I am currently making a React Native (Expo) background image which I'm hoping to turn into a dynamic background. I want the background to be able to fit any screen the user is viewing the app from.

The width of the image would ideally stretch to fit the size of the screen being viewed, and the height would ideally repeat for however long the screen size of the current screen ends up being. I'm hoping to keep the sides of the image the same size as they appear below, but add or increase the space in the middle of the SVG to fit the screen size.

I'm not just looking to alter the size of the SVG, but also the size of elements within the SVG itself; specifically the middle section.

Below is the SVG I am working with:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="1465" height="565" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1465 565">
    <g mask="url(&quot;#SvgjsMask1076&quot;)" fill="none">
        <rect width="1465" height="565" x="0" y="0" fill="#1a4e83"></rect>
        <path d="M0 0L541.72 0L0 1014.36z" filter="url(#SvgjsFilter1077)" fill="#2d409e"></path>
        <path d="M0 565L541.72 565L0 -449.36z" filter="url(#SvgjsFilter1077)" fill="#2d409e"></path>
        <path d="M1465 565L923.28 565L1465 -449.36z" filter="url(#SvgjsFilter1077)" fill="#2d409e"></path>
        <path d="M1465 0L923.28 0L1465 1014.36z" filter="url(#SvgjsFilter1077)" fill="#2d409e"></path>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <mask id="SvgjsMask1076">
            <rect width="1465" height="565" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
        </mask>
        <filter height="130%" id="SvgjsFilter1077">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" result="TopLeftG"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset dx="-5" dy="-5" in="TopLeftG" result="TopLeftO"></feOffset>
            <feComponentTransfer in="TopLeftO" result="TopLeftC">
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.7"></feFuncA>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" result="TopRightG"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset dx="5" dy="-5" in="TopRightG" result="TopRightO"></feOffset>
            <feComponentTransfer in="TopRightO" result="TopRightC">
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.7"></feFuncA>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" result="BottomLeftG"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset dx="-5" dy="5" in="BottomLeftG" result="BottomLeftO"></feOffset>
            <feComponentTransfer in="BottomLeftO" result="BottomLeftC">
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.7"></feFuncA>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" result="BottomRightG"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" in="BottomRightG" result="BottomRightO"></feOffset>
            <feComponentTransfer in="BottomRightO" result="BottomRightC">
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.7"></feFuncA>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="TopLeftC"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="TopRightC"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="BottomLeftC"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="BottomRightC"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: _"I'm not just looking to alter the size of the SVG, but also the size of elements within the SVG itself; specifically the middle section."_ - Please be more specific, your question is still too vague. While it is certainly possible to make SVG images "responsive" and dynamic w.r.t. their rendered size, it usually requires scripting or gnarly SVG-specific CSS - so usually people just have a fixed SVG image with `object-fit: cover;` (for `<img/>`) or `background-size: cover;` (for `background-image:`).